# Getting the color of a datapoint when in the jqplotMouseMove event

Tags: jqplot

I have an event handler declared as:

```
.on('jqplotMouseMove', function (e, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot)
```

If neighbor is true I need to find the color of the datapoint they
clicked on. Is there some method I can call that will give me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the seriesIndex from the neighbor variable, which you can use to get the color.

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotMouseMove',
   function (e, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {                
     if (neighbor != null){
        alert(plot1.series[neighbor.seriesIndex].color);
     }
  }
);
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SSRVj/3/).

Comment: The action I need to take needs to occur when the user moves his mouse over the datapoint, not just when they click on it. Is there some way to get the seriesIndex from the jqplotMouseMove event?

Comment: See edits.  You should use the `jqplotDataMouseOver` event then.

Comment: This is an existing program that I need to modify to add new functionality to. It already has the `.on('jqplotMouseMove', function (e, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot)` function where a lot of things happen using data that is in neighbor. I also need data from neighbor to do my new stuff.